# muddatagrid - access filtered records programmatically

Tags: mudblazor

I have a muddatagrid like this which has got the filters and i am able to filter it. Programmatically how can I get the filtered records?

```
<MudDataGrid Items="@Elements" @ref="dg" Filterable="true" FilterCaseSensitivity=DataGridFilterCaseSensitivity.CaseInsensitive>
    <Columns>
        
       <Column T="RequestInfo" Field="RequestId" Title="Request ID" />
       <Column T="RequestInfo" Field="ProjectName" Title="Project Name" />
       <Column T="RequestInfo" Field="RequestCreatedBy"   Title="Created By" />
      
    </Columns>
   <NoRecordsContent>
        <MudText>No matching records found</MudText>
    </NoRecordsContent>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudDataGridPager T="RequestInfo" />
    </PagerContent>
</MudDataGrid>


@code
{
     MudDataGrid<RequestInfo> dg;

 private async Task somefunction()
    {
       //this function is invoked after pressing a button in the page and all the filters have been applied.

        List<RequestInfo> ll = dg.FilteredItems as List<RequestInfo>;
       
  
      
    }
}
```

This function returns always 0 items. How Do I get to see only the filtered items programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dg.FilteredItems` probably isn't a `List` when you apply filters. Instead of `... as List<RequestInfo>`, call `.ToList()` on it:

```cs
@code
{
    MudDataGrid<RequestInfo> dg;

    private async Task somefunction()
    {
        List<RequestInfo> ll = dg.FilteredItems.ToList();
        ...
    }
}
```

> whats the difference between dg.FilteredItems.ToList(); and dg.FilteredItems as List;

The code:

```cs
dg.FilteredItems as List<RequestInfo>
```

is equivalent to:

```cs
dg.FilteredItems is List<RequestInfo> 
  ? (List<RequestInfo>)dg.FilteredItems 
  : (List<RequestInfo>)null
```

This means that if the `IEnumerable` `dg.FilteredItems` is not a `List`, `null` will be returned.

The code:

```cs
dg.FilteredItems.ToList()
```

will return a new `List`, no matter what `IEnumerable` `dg.FilteredItems` behind the scenes is (an array, a `IList`, a `ISet`, ...)

Comment: it sovled the problem, but whats the difference between dg.FilteredItems.ToList(); and dg.FilteredItems as List<RequestInfo>;