# Programmatically loop through the rows of a MudDataGrid

Tags: blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

How can I access and manipulate individual rows in a MudDataGrid within a Blazor WebAssembly application using C#? Specifically, I want to change the background color or remove rows programmatically.
[Sample Project](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wuQRPkcKfmviLAgN)

Similar question but different context ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75376810/muddatagrid-access-filtered-records-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could access and modify the specific Person in the People IEnummerable. I'm using a `List` instead of an `IEnummerable`, just so I can use `Remove`, `RemoveAt`.

To remove a row you can use

```
private void RemoveRow(int index)
{
  People.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

To change the background-color use the `RowStyleFunc` of the DataGrid. But before add a new Property `ColorCode` on Person

```
public record Person(string Name, int Age, string State, string ColorCode){
  public string ColorCode{get; set;}
}
```

And use and define the RowStyleFunc of the DataGrid

```
<MudDataGrid T="Person" Items="@People" ColumnResizeMode="ResizeMode.Container" @ref="mudGrid" RowStyleFunc="@_rowStyleFunc">


private Func<Person, int, string> _rowStyleFunc => (x, i) =>
{
  // clear all rowStyles
  string style = string.Empty;
  style += $"background-color:#{x.ColorCode}";

  return style;
};
```

And finally a method to change the property `ColorCode`

```
private async void ChangeRowBackgroundColor(int index)
{
  People[index].ColorCode = "FFFFFF";
}
```

Additionally you can also add Buttons to each row and access the person there

```
<Columns>
    <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" CellStyle="max-width: 100px; overflow-x: hidden; white-space: nowrap;" />
    <TemplateColumn T="Person" TProperty="String" Sortable="false" Filterable="false" Title="Buttons">
        <CellTemplate>
            <MudMenu Label="Actions" Variant="Variant.Filled" DisableElevation="true"
                     EndIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown" IconColor="Color.Secondary" TransformOrigin="Origin.TopLeft">
                <MudMenuItem OnClick="@(async () => await RemovePerson(context.Item))">Remove me!</MudMenuItem>
                <MudMenuItem OnClick="@(async () => await ColorPerson(context.Item))">Color Me!</MudMenuItem>
            </MudMenu>
        </CellTemplate>
    </TemplateColumn>
</Columns>




private async Task RemovePerson(Person person)
{
  People.Remove(person);
}
```

[Snippet with examples](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QEmnlOcLwRDkGwsy)